# Partition an existing partition for installing an OS?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, arch-linux

I am trying to install multiple OS's as an experiment: my disk is already partitioned into 5 partitions as seen below:

[image]

Partition 2 contains a Linux mint installation, while partition 3 contains a Windows OS, partition 4 contains data.

I wish to use partition 5: `/dev/nvme0n1p5` (size = 50 GB, red arrow) for installing Arch Linux which, based on my previous experiences on a disk with a single partition,  is typically done with the following 4 partitions:

1. EFI partition (I am using uefi bios with a gpt partition scheme) (size = 512 MB)
2. Root partition (size = 15 GB)
3. Home partition (size = 32.5 GB)
4. Swap partition (size = 2 GB)

So I tried the above setup from a live Arch Linux environment using the `fdisk` utility on partition 5: `/dev/nvme0n1p5`. When I printed `p` the partition table within `fdisk`, I got the following result (I'm paraphrasing because I couldnt screenshot within the live environment):

```
Partition           Size       Type
/dev/nvme0n1p5p1    512 MiB    Linux Filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p5p2    15 GiB     Linux Filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p5p3    32.5 GiB   Linux Filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p5p4    2 GiB      Linux Filesystem
```

However on writing, `fdisk` failed with error (I'm paraphrasing again): "Invalid argument. Kernel needs to re-read partition table upon rebooting" and suggested using `partprobe` or `partx` (which I tried but it did not help).

I have definitely corrupted the partition as evident from the message below:

[image]

What should I do to fix this partition and after that, is there anything I can do at this point to install Arch Linux onto this partition with the above mentioned 4 partitions?

Comment: what happens when you try to make a new file system on the partion?. e.g `sudo mkfs.btrfs /dev/vnme0n1p5` - you might have to use the -f flag to force. Note: i suggested btrfs over ext4 - i think that will make your life easier. FYI I dont think you can have an efi partition thats not at the start of the disk - I think you should use your existing efi partition. I dont claim to be an expert though,

Comment: if that's all working you can use btrfs sub-volumes for your root, swap and home partitions and resize them easily as needed - also easy backups

Comment: I will try that. Would it be possible to use an MBR partition scheme instead on ONLY partition 5 with a boot partition in the beginning of itself? I have used GPT/uEFI on all of the other partitions so my question really is: can you have both MBR and GPT on the same disk on different partitions?

Comment: No, GPT/MBR is a property of the disk, not of the partition.

Comment: okay got it.  For instance, when  I start `fdisk` on partition 5, i am asked to specify gpt or dos and 2 other options i cant recall. Can I specify `dos` then? What would happen then? Im just curious: would that simply result in an error?

Comment: please take this with a pinch of salt because maybe you can partition a partition (i haven't tried): i think you are using fdisk wrong. I would only use fdisk on an actual disk, you are using fdisk on a partition. this is why i suggest using btrfs subvolumes for your particular setup... some people use lvm for similar 'subvolumes' setup on ext4, but that's a bit more complicated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is my understanding (some details may be a bit off)

**Issue 1)** You are using fdisk on a partition instead of a disk. fdisk seems to have destroyed your file system on that partition for you as a result.

`/dev/nvme0n1p5` is the partition `/dev/nvme0n1` is the disk (and I believe `/dev/nvme0` is the controller, but we don't care about that)

**Issue 2)** I'm pretty sure you can only have one efi partition per disk and it has to be at the start of the disk and in fat32 format [**Edit/Correction:** You can have multiple efi partitions on one disk, though still not recommended]. You probably want to be using your existing efi partition (you can still set boot precedence... If you set everything up correctly (mounts to /boot/efi), grub should handle the efi setup for you without upsetting your other installs.

You have two ways of moving forward:

**Option 1 *(riskier for existing partitions IMHO)*** - you can use a tool like `parted` to shrink your 5th partition and then create more partitions in the unused space... this has some overhead in disk space and you are running a pretty tight ship as it is... additionally it will be a pain to resize these partitions once they have data on them.

**Option 2 *(recommended)***, just remake your file system on partition 5 and then use subvolumes for root, swap and home (and whatever else you need)

I would recommend formatting partition 5 to btrfs (all commands probably need sudo):
`mkfs.btrfs -f /dev/nvme0n1p5`

Then to create the subvolumes with btrfs (ext4/lvm is an alternative you could look at):

**mount your partition:**

`mkdir /mnt/brtfs`

`mount /dev/nvme0n1p5 /mnt/btrfs`

**then create the subvolumes:**

`btrfs subvolume create /mnt/btrfs/@` to create a new mount for root

`btrfs subvolume create /mnt/btrfs/@swap` for swap

`btrfs subvolume create /mnt/btrfs/@home` for home

***Warning: Don't store anything in the root of your btrfs partition other than subvolumes***

Note: the `@` is just a convention to remind you its a subvolume - you can call them whatever you want but doing that will remind you not to break the golden rule above

Depending on your setup you may need to unmount the root btrfs partition and remount to nest volumes correctly in the filesystem but for your setup you should be able to just mount the efi partition at /mnt/btrfs/@/boot/efi and work from there (and see swap at the end)

Once you have installed the base system you can setup your new fstab to reference these volumes, something like this:

```
UUID=782d3829-b893-283h-ade9-d9a34da2084682 /boot/efi      vfat    umask=0077 0 2
UUID=346b428-b632-440f-abc3-a3dcefs12379983 /              btrfs   subvol=/@,defaults,noatime,compress=zstd,discard=async,ss
d 0 0
UUID=346b428-b632-440f-abc3-a3dcefs12379983 /home          btrfs   subvol=/@home,defaults,noatime,compress=zstd,discard=asyn
c,ssd 0 0
```

You will want an entry for your swap as well - see here for an example https://askubuntu.com/questions/1206157/can-i-have-a-swapfile-on-btrfs

Comment: No, there was never a requirement that there should be only one ESP and it should be first partition. It's just pointless to have more that one.

Comment: Ah ok - I will add a correction.

Answer (score 1):

To use any devices in Linux you need corresponding device nodes (special file system objects that appear partially like files). During discovery the kernel parses a partition table on the newly found device and calls `udev` to create the corresponding device nodes in `/dev` (in the past, system administrator managed *static `/dev`* and created those nodes by hand).

The problem is, it only parses the partition table once on a base device. It doesn't expect any similar structure within discovered partitions, and doesn't parse them. By "partitioning the partition" you create the necessary structures, but those are for nobody. What you are doing simply couldn't work and I suppose it will never work because actually nobody needs that.

(Also I doubt it is possible to create any nodes for "subpartitions" by hand because there are no such major/minor pairs which kernel will interpret as "partitions within partitions".)

There is still some limited use for them; one thing that comes to my mind is that you can forward a partition into virtual machine, where it will be seen as a whole disk, so the OS in the VM *will* interpret this structure.

So, what you are asking about is pointless. But you seem to be using GPT on your disk, which allows for as many as 128 partitions. This is plenty. Don't hesitate and just create additional partitions on the base device: `fdisk /dev/nvme0n1`.

Also, you don't need to create additional ESP. You can, but it will not be used. You already have one, in the beginning of the disk, `/dev/nvme0n1p1`.